# Continue the program execution in multiple try-catch statements scenario after catching exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have the following code running in my project:

```
HashMap<String, DeviceData> deviceMap = getAllDevices();

int status = 0;
DeviceHandle devHandle = null;

for (LicenseData licenseData:listLicenses) {

    Map<String, String> licenseMap = licenseData.getLicenseKeyValues();     

    if ((licenseMap != null && !licenseMap.isEmpty())) {
        String keyDecrypt = licenseMap.get("key");
        Date expiryDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(licenseMap.get("expiryDate")));
        boolean allowForeign = Boolean.parseBoolean(licenseMap.get("allowForeign"));
        String ipDecrypt = licenseMap.get("ipAddress");

        if (expiryDate.compareTo(new Date()) > 0 || keyDecrypt.equals(licenseData.getKey().getCurrentValueAsString())) 
        {
            try {
                DeviceData device =  deviceMap.get(ipDecrypt);
                devHandle = (DeviceHandle)device.getHandle();

                if(device != null && devHandle != null) {
                    deviceMap.remove(ipDecrypt, device);
                    System.out.println("After deletion device map.");
                    System.out.println(deviceMap);
                    createUser(devHandle);

                    try {
                        if (allowForeign) {
                            Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SomeOperation);
                            status = pr.waitFor();
                            if (status == 0) 
                                //Debug Statement
                            else 
                                //Error Debug Statemnt

                            deleteUser(devHandle);
                        }

                        else {
                            Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SomeOperation);
                            status = pr.waitFor();
                            if (status == 0) 
                                //Debug Statement
                            else 
                                //Error Debug Statement

                        deleteUser(devHandle);
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        //Exception statement
                        deleteUser(devHandle);
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: I have a list of licenses for my application in listLicenses. All the devices present in the server are in deviceMap. For each license, I am decrypting it and getting the values. If license for a device is present, I get a handle on that device and doing some operations.

The issue is: 
If I am not able to get a handle on device(getHandle()), or if I am not able to create a user after getting the device handle(createUser()), an exception is thrown. These methods are very hierarchical, i.e I am calling them from here, they are in another class throwing own exceptions and for their operation, they call other methods.

If there are three devices in the map, and three licenses, and if for the first one I am not able to get a handle or create a user, device is removed from deviceMap but no further execution happens i.e. for the next two devices.

If exception occurs for on device, I want to continue the exception for other two devices. I tried using return but couldn't get it to work. 
Please help.Also, please forgive for the syntax and if any mismatch is there in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of first try's catch block.

This is how I handled when I faced same kind of situation.

```
catch (Exception exp) {

if (exp instanceof NullPointerException) {
    log.info"Invalid/ Inactive ");
} else if (exp instanceof NonUniqueResultException) {
    log.info("Multiple records existed");
} else {
    exp.printStackTrace();
    errorMsgs.append("Unexpected Error Occured. Please contact Admin.");                
}
}
```

Comment: Even if exception is caught, how to go back to the program and run my for loop again?

Comment: Did you try the above solution ? In my case, I'd 5 records in list where exception caught at 2nd record. But after using above it continued and finished processing all the 5

Comment: In my project, we have several different exception specified and it cannot be determined which one it will throw, and also the other classes' methods it is calling throw exceptions of their own